# iOS - How to save an image from multiple UIImageView?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiimageview, uiimage

I want to do something really simple which is select a picture from the iPhone library add it to my view. Then add another little image (let's say a cartoon smile in PNG) to my view and then when I click in a UIBarButtonItem save the result in my photo library.

I know how to save a UIImage to my library but I don't know how to create a JPG from the my view (without the toolbar !) with good quality.
I tried doing a snapshot but I got a little image (resolution) with a poor quality !

Do you have any idea how I could do this ?

Thanks in advance !

Edit : My code for the snapshot

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.editableView.frame.size);
[self.editableView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage * image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

I even tried this trick to save it as PNG !

```
UIImage* im = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:image.CGImage]; // make image from CGRef
NSData* imdata =  UIImagePNGRepresentation ( im ); // get PNG representation
UIImage* im2 = [UIImage imageWithData:imdata]; // wrap UIImage around PNG representation


UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(im2, self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
```

Comment: What code are you using to snapshot?

Comment: @AntonHolmquist I just edited my post

Comment: Try using UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.editableView.frame.size, YES, 0.0) to get a higher quality image.

Comment: @AntonHolmquist Looks a little bit better but the colors aren't really bright compare to the view in my app. Do you have an idea ?

Comment: If you have any non-opaque parts to the image you may be missing the effects of that, in which case do UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.editableView.frame.size, NO, 0.0)